# I'm Trying to make a sign up form and then a log in form

Tags: python, tkinter

**Im trying to make a sign up form using tkinter module which collects the username and password, and after that a log in form pops up so u have to type in your username and password again, but it isn't working.**

i made two variables to store the name and passcode entered in the sign up form

```
sign_up_name = StringVar()
sign_up_code = StringVar()
```

after entering the name and code and storing it and then clicking the sign up button it opens and new form to log in.

I made a function which creates two new variables to store the name and passcode entered in log in form

```
log_in_name = StringVar() 
log_in_code = StringVar()
```

and i also made the variables for the name and passcode in the signup form global

```
global sign_up_name        
global sign_up_code
```

I then made the whole screen in the same function and also used textvariable = log_in_name and textvariable = log_in_code in the entries

then I made another function inside the same function which is called when the log in button is pressed and in that function I check if the log_in_name variable is the same as the sign_up_name
and if the log_in_code is the same as the sign_up_code

```
if log_in_name.get() == sign_up_name.get()and log_in_code.get() == sign_up_code.get():
        messagebox.showinfo("Loged In!", "Successfully Loged In!")

    else:
        messagebox.showwarning("Error!", "Wrong Name Or Passcode! Try Again!!")
```

but what happens is that the sign up part works perfectly but at the end it keeps displaying the error message even though I enter the same name and passcode in both the log in form and sign in form.

i even made it print the sign_up_name, log_in_name, sign_up_code, and log_in_code to see and for the sign_up_name and sign_up_code it would print whatever I entered in the entry, but for the log_in_code and log_in_name it would print nothing. I have no idea what's wrong and I even made the variables global everywhere. Please help. Here is the whole code if needed:

```
#importing modules
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

#making the sign up screen 
sc = Tk()
sc.geometry("450x450")
sc.configure(background="#F0F8FF")
sc.title("Sign Up")

#two string variables to store the name and passcode_login entered i n the sign up form
sign_up_name = StringVar()
sign_up_code = StringVar()



#function to check if length of name and mail and code is okay
def check():
    sc.quit
    if len(sign_up_name.get()) >= 3 and len(mailentry.get()) >= 10 and len(sign_up_code.get()) >= 6:
        messagebox.showinfo("Account Created!" , "Account Created Succesfully! Please Login Again To View Your Report Card!")
        print("Sign Up\nUsername: ", sign_up_name.get(), "\n Passcode: ", sign_up_code.get())
        login()
        

    else:
        messagebox.showwarning("Error", "Please Make Sure Your Username Length Is Greater Than 3, Your Passcode Has More Than 6 Charecters, And Please Enter A Valid Email!")


#function to open the log in screen and check everything
def login():


    log_in_name = StringVar() #variable to store the name enetered in log in screen 
    log_in_code = StringVar() #variable to store the passcode enetered in log in screen
    #making both variables global so i can use them to check
    global sign_up_name        
    global sign_up_code

    #making the log in screen 
    wn = Tk()
    wn.geometry("450x450")
    wn.configure(background="#e8ffd6")
    wn.title("Login")

    #just labels
    sign_label = Label(wn, text="Log In To See Your Report Card! " , font=("Beachday", 23, "normal"), fg="black", bg="#e8ffd6")
    sign_label.pack()

    name_label = Label(wn, text="Username: ", font=("Chicken Pie Height", 19,"normal"), fg="black", bg="#e8ffd6")
    name_label.place(x = 30, y = 100)

    passw = Label(wn, text="Passcode:  ", font=("Chicken Pie Height", 19,"normal"), fg="black", bg="#e8ffd6")
    passw.place(x = 30, y = 260)

    #entries to get name and passcode
    name_login = Entry(wn, bg="#d8ffb9", fg = "black", bd=1, textvariable = log_in_name, font = ("212 Baby Girl", 15, "normal"))
    name_login.place(x = 200,  y = 106)

    code_login = Entry(wn, bg="#d8ffb9", fg = "black", bd=1, textvariable = log_in_code,  font = ("212 Baby Girl", 15, "normal"))
    code_login.place(x = 200,  y = 266)
    #log in button
    log = Button(wn, text="Log In", font=("212 Baby Girl", 17, "bold"), bg="#d8ffb9", activebackground="#d8ffb9", command=logged)
    log.place(x = 90, y = 350)
    #cancel button to close screen
    can = Button(wn, text="Cancel", font=("212 Baby Girl", 17, "bold"), bg="#d8ffb9", activebackground="#d8ffb9",command=quit)
    can.place(x = 300, y = 350)

#function to check if the name and passcode entered in the log in form is the same as the one
    #enetered in sign up form
    def logged():
        #making variables global to use them 
        global sign_up_name
        global sign_up_code

        #printing the name and passcode enetered in log in form (only for me to see if it was working)
        print("Log In: \n Username: ", log_in_name.get() , "\nPasscode: ", log_in_code.get())
        #condition to check if name and passcode given in login form is same as name and passcode
        #given in sign up form
        if log_in_name.get() == sign_up_name.get()and log_in_code.get() == sign_up_code.get():
            #message box if name and passcode matched
            messagebox.showinfo("Loged In!", "Successfully Loged In!")

        else:
            #gives error if not matched
            messagebox.showwarning("Error!", "Wrong Name Or Passcode! Try Again!!")

#setting up sign up screen 
#labels
sign_label = Label(sc, text="Sign Up To See Your Report Card! " , font=("Beachday", 23, "normal"), fg="black", bg="#F0F8FF")
sign_label.pack()

name_login_label = Label(sc, text="Username: ", font=("Chicken Pie Height", 19,"normal"), fg="black", bg="#F0F8FF")
name_login_label.place(x = 30, y = 100)

maill = Label(sc, text="Email: ", font=("Chicken Pie Height", 19,"normal"), fg="black", bg="#F0F8FF")
maill.place(x = 30, y = 180)

passw = Label(sc, text="Passcode:  ", font=("Chicken Pie Height", 19,"normal"), fg="black", bg="#F0F8FF")
passw.place(x = 30, y = 260)

#entry for name
name_signUp = Entry(sc, bg="#eaf6fe", fg = "black", bd=1,  textvariable = sign_up_name, font = ("212 Baby Girl", 15, "normal"))
name_signUp.place(x = 200,  y = 106)
#entry for mail 
mailentry = Entry(sc, bg="#eaf6fe", fg = "black", bd=1,  font = ("212 Baby Girl", 15, "normal"))
mailentry.place(x = 200,  y = 186)
#entry for code
code_signUp = Entry(sc, bg="#eaf6fe", fg = "black", textvariable = sign_up_code,  bd=1,  font = ("212 Baby Girl", 15, "normal"))
code_signUp.place(x = 200,  y = 266)
#submit button
submit = Button(sc, text="Sign Up", font=("212 Baby Girl", 17, "bold"), bg="#ADD8E6", activebackground="#AFDCEB", command=check)
submit.place(x = 90, y = 350)
#cancel button
cancel = Button(sc, text="Cancel", font=("212 Baby Girl", 17, "bold"), bg="#ADD8E6", activebackground="#AFDCEB",command=quit)
cancel.place(x = 300, y = 350)

sc.mainloop()
```

Comment: It is because you have two instances of `Tk`.  Use `Toplevel` for `wn` inside `login()`.

Answer (score 0):

> and after that a log in form pops up so u have to type in your
> username and password again, but it isn't working.

> for the sign_up_name and sign_up_code it would print whatever I
> entered in the entry, but for the log_in_code and log_in_name it would
> print nothing.

Importing every public name from a module using a wildcard (`from tkinter import *`) is a bad idea because:

- It could lead to conflicts between names defined locally and the ones
  imported.

The problem can be fix.

- Move `log_in_name` and `log_in_code` outside before `check()`
  function.
- Remove all `global`. You don't need this.
- Move `logged()`  outside of `login()` function. So the `Button`
  command will activate.

In `Login()` function, you cannot open main window. You already had `sc = Tk()`.

- So, replace `wn = Toplevel()`, instead of `wn = Tk()`. The `Toplevel()` means opening a new window not a main window.

Snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

#making the sign up screen 
sc = tk.Tk()
sc.geometry("450x450")
sc.configure(background="#F0F8FF")
sc.title("Sign Up")

#two string variables to store the name and passcode_login entered i n the sign up form
sign_up_name = tk.StringVar()
sign_up_code = tk.StringVar()

log_in_name = tk.StringVar() #variable to store the name enetered in log in screen 
log_in_code = tk.StringVar()



#function to check if length of name and mail and code is okay
def check():
    sc.quit
    if len(sign_up_name.get()) >= 3 and len(mailentry.get()) >= 10 and len(sign_up_code.get()) >= 6:
        messagebox.showinfo("Account Created!" , "Account Created Succesfully! Please Login Again To View Your Report Card!")
        print("Sign Up\nUsername: ", sign_up_name.get(), "\n Passcode: ", sign_up_code.get())
        login()
        

    else:
        messagebox.showwarning("Error", "Please Make Sure Your Username Length Is Greater Than 3, Your Passcode Has More Than 6 Charecters, And Please Enter A Valid Email!")


#function to open the log in screen and check everything
def login():

    
    #making the log in screen 
    wn = tk.Toplevel()
    wn.geometry("450x450")
    wn.configure(background="#e8ffd6")
    wn.title("Login")

    #just labels
    sign_label = tk.Label(wn, text="Log In To See Your Report Card! " , font=("Beachday", 23, "normal"), fg="black", bg="#e8ffd6")
    sign_label.pack()

    name_label = tk.Label(wn, text="Username: ", font=("Chicken Pie Height", 19,"normal"), fg="black", bg="#e8ffd6")
    name_label.place(x = 30, y = 100)

    passw = tk.Label(wn, text="Passcode:  ", font=("Chicken Pie Height", 19,"normal"), fg="black", bg="#e8ffd6")
    passw.place(x = 30, y = 260)

    #entries to get name and passcode
    name_login = tk.Entry(wn, bg="#d8ffb9", fg = "black", bd=1, textvariable = log_in_name, font = ("212 Baby Girl", 15, "normal"))
    name_login.place(x = 200,  y = 106)

    code_login = tk.Entry(wn, bg="#d8ffb9", fg = "black", bd=1, textvariable = log_in_code,  font = ("212 Baby Girl", 15, "normal"))
    code_login.place(x = 200,  y = 266)
    #log in button
    log = tk.Button(wn, text="Log In", font=("212 Baby Girl", 17, "bold"), bg="#d8ffb9", activebackground="#d8ffb9", command=logged)
    log.place(x = 90, y = 350)
    #cancel button to close screen
    can = tk.Button(wn, text="Cancel", font=("212 Baby Girl", 17, "bold"), bg="#d8ffb9", activebackground="#d8ffb9",command=quit)
    can.place(x = 300, y = 350)

#function to check if the name and passcode entered in the log in form is the same as the one
    #enetered in sign up form
def logged():
    #making variables global to use them 
     

    #printing the name and passcode enetered in log in form (only for me to see if it was working)
    print("Log In: \n Username: ", log_in_name.get() , "\nPasscode: ", log_in_code.get())
    #condition to check if name and passcode given in login form is same as name and passcode
    #given in sign up form
    if log_in_name.get() == sign_up_name.get()and log_in_code.get() == sign_up_code.get():
        #message box if name and passcode matched
        messagebox.showinfo("Loged In!", "Successfully Loged In!")

    else:
        #gives error if not matched
        messagebox.showwarning("Error!", "Wrong Name Or Passcode! Try Again!!")

#setting up sign up screen 
#labels
sign_label = tk.Label(sc, text="Sign Up To See Your Report Card! " , font=("Beachday", 23, "normal"), fg="black", bg="#F0F8FF")
sign_label.pack()

name_login_label = tk.Label(sc, text="Username: ", font=("Chicken Pie Height", 19,"normal"), fg="black", bg="#F0F8FF")
name_login_label.place(x = 30, y = 100)

maill = tk.Label(sc, text="Email: ", font=("Chicken Pie Height", 19,"normal"), fg="black", bg="#F0F8FF")
maill.place(x = 30, y = 180)

passw = tk.Label(sc, text="Passcode:  ", font=("Chicken Pie Height", 19,"normal"), fg="black", bg="#F0F8FF")
passw.place(x = 30, y = 260)

#entry for name
name_signUp = tk.Entry(sc, bg="#eaf6fe", fg = "black", bd=1,  textvariable = sign_up_name, font = ("212 Baby Girl", 15, "normal"))
name_signUp.place(x = 200,  y = 106)
#entry for mail 
mailentry = tk.Entry(sc, bg="#eaf6fe", fg = "black", bd=1,  font = ("212 Baby Girl", 15, "normal"))
mailentry.place(x = 200,  y = 186)
#entry for code
code_signUp = tk.Entry(sc, bg="#eaf6fe", fg = "black", textvariable = sign_up_code,  bd=1,  font = ("212 Baby Girl", 15, "normal"))
code_signUp.place(x = 200,  y = 266)
#submit button
submit = tk.Button(sc, text="Sign Up", font=("212 Baby Girl", 17, "bold"), bg="#ADD8E6", activebackground="#AFDCEB", command=check)
submit.place(x = 90, y = 350)
#cancel button
cancel = tk.Button(sc, text="Cancel", font=("212 Baby Girl", 17, "bold"), bg="#ADD8E6", activebackground="#AFDCEB",command=quit)
cancel.place(x = 300, y = 350)

sc.mainloop()
```

Screenshot for Sign in:

[image]

Screenshot for Loginin:

[image]